# Como crear un Diccionario de listas?

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

Tengo 2 listas:

```
lista_llaves = [key1, key2, key3...key1000] # con 1000 llaves

lista_valores = [valor_key1_1, valor_key1_2, valor_key2_1,
                 valor_key2_2, valor_key3_1... valor_key1000_1] # con 4000 valores
```

en donde una llave puede tener varios valores correspondientes...

Creo un Diccionario de Listas:

```
dict_valores = dict(zip(lista_llaves, [[]]*len(lista_llaves)))

print(dict_valores)
dict_valores = { "key1":[], "key2":[], "key3":[]... key1000:[]}
```

si la llave esta dentro del valor:

```
if llave == valor.split("_")[1]: # "key1" in "valor_key1_1" ### se me ocurre
```

1. como recorro uno a uno las llaves de la lista_llaves?
2. como verifico si la llave esta dentro del valor en la lista_valores?
3. como agrego al dict_valores[llave]?

Resultado:

```
dict_valores = 
{ "key1":[valor_key1_1, valor_key1_2...], 
  "key2":[valor_key2_1, valor_key2_2...], 
  "key3":[valor_key3_1, valor_key4_2...],
  ...
  "key1000":[valor_key1000_1, valor_key1000_2...]}
```

Por su tiempo gracias, comunidad.

Comment: No me queda claro qué hay en la lista de valores. ¿Te estás refieriendo a que tienes una lista de 4000 variables y quieres procesarlas por su nombre?

Comment: son nombre de archivos en un directorio. muchas gracias por arreglar el estilo de la publicación, ya lo estaba haciendo cuando me llego tu notificación.

Comment: lo quise hacer lo mas generico posible para que sea mas funcional, pero en la realidad, son galerias fotograficas de productos, que necesito agrupar por referencia de producto, pero cada galeria varia en la cantidad de imagenes, el nombre de la imagen tiene la referencia del producto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lista_llaves = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'] # con 1000 llaves

lista_valores = ['key1_1', 'key1_2', 'key2_1', 'key2_2', 'key3_1', 'key1000_3']
```

Poblar el diccionario con las llaves:

```
diccionario = {k: [] for k in lista_llaves}
```

A continuación recorrer los elementos de la lista de valores. Separar cada elemento por la "_", obteniendo llave y valor.

Usar `if key in diccionario` para chequear que la llave existe.

Si la llave existe, hacer un append del nuevo valor.

```
for elem in lista_valores:
    key, val = elem.split("_")
    if key in diccionario:
        diccionario[key].append(val)
```

y luego imprimirlo.

```
print(dictionario)
```

produce

```
{'key1': ['1', '2'], 'key2': ['1', '2'], 'key3': ['1']}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: print(diccionario) no puedo corregirlo por que deben ser minimo 6 caracteres.... MUCHAS GRACIAS

Answer (score 0):

Para crear un diccionario de listas donde las llaves provienen de una lista lista_llaves y los valores provienen de otra lista lista_valores, puedes utilizar un bucle for para iterar sobre las llaves y verificar si están presentes en los valores.

```
lista_llaves = ["key1", "key2", "key3", "key1", "key2"]
lista_valores = ["valor_key1_1", "valor_key2_1", "valor_key3_1", "valor_key1_2", "valor_key2_2"]
dict_valores = {}
for llave, valor in zip(lista_llaves, lista_valores):
if llave not in dict_valores:
    dict_valores[llave] = []
dict_valores[llave].append(valor)
print(dict_valores)
```

El bucle for recorre las dos listas al mismo tiempo, emparejando cada clave con su valor correspondiente. La condición if llave not in dict_valores verifica si la clave ya está en el diccionario. Si no lo está, se crea una nueva entrada con una lista vacía.

Comment: El código está mal indentando. Además, si cambias el orden de lista_valores, el código ya no funciona correctamente.